# $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, what is the gradient of $f(tx)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Fairly simple question, suppose there is a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, and a scalar $t \in \mathbb R$.

is it possible to find $D_f(tx)$ using only $t$ and $D_f(x)$? Perhaps using chain rule?

Clarification: $D_f(x)$ is the matrix (or in this case, vector) of partial derivatives at $x$

Can we even say anything about $f(tx)$? if we take it to the realm of $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, we can't even know for sure that it is differentiable there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\varphi : \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ be defined by $\varphi(t,x) = tx$. Then what you're looking at is the derivative of $f \circ \varphi$. You then have $D(f \circ \varphi)(t,x) = Df(\varphi(t,x)) \circ D\varphi(t,x)$  by the chain rule.

Comment: The result I got for $D_\phi (x)$ is the identity matrix times $t$. so overall we have: $D_f(\phi(x)) \times tI=tD_f(\phi (x))$

Comment: $\varphi : \Bbb{R}^{n+1} \to \Bbb{R}^n$, so $D\varphi(t,x)$ will be an $n \times n+1$ matrix, so it can't be the identity. You are close though.

Comment: I defined phi differently, i said $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, $\phi (x)=tx$, where I know $t$. it is not a variable.

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear in the question, but $t$ is a number for all purposes. It is not a variable. so when you write $\phi (t,x)$ and then you find partial derivatives with respect to $t$, that amounts to find partial derivatives with respect to 5, or 9, or any number.

Answer (score 1):

What you call $D_f(x)$ is for all purposes the gradient of $f$ at the point $x$, denoted by $\nabla f(x)$ by many. As a consequence the term $D_f(tx)=\nabla f(tx)$ denotes the gradient of $f$ at the point $tx$. This gradient vector is attached to the point $tx$ far away from $x$. Unless $f$ has special long-range properties the vector $\nabla f(tx)$ is in no way related to the vector $\nabla f(x)$.

It is another story if for given $f:\ {\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ and given scalar $t$ you consider the *new function*
$$g(x):=f(tx)\ .$$
For the derivative of this "contracted copy of $f\,$" the chain rule indeed applies: You can write
$$g=f\circ T\ ,$$
where $T$ is given by  $T:\ x\mapsto tx$. According to the chain rule we then have
$$dg(x)=df(Tx)\circ dT(x)=df(Tx)\circ T=t\ df(Tx)\ ,$$
which can also be written as
$$\nabla g(x)=t\ \nabla f(tx)\ .$$