# $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(tx) = tf(x)$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(0) = f(v)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Show that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = 0$
>   and $f(tx) = tf(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $t\neq 0$ has all
>   directional derivatives at origin and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  v}(0) = f(v)$$

At first I'd calculate the gradient, but there's no 'general rule' for the function. Also, what is $f(v)$ supposed to be?

I thought of using the chain rule at the equation $f(tx) = tf(x)$ to see if that gave me something, but I couldn't.

Then, I found this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/845097/166180 but it only explains how to do the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of partial derivative in direction $v$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}  (x_0)=\lim_\limits{t\to0}\frac{f(x_0+tv)-f(x_0)}{t}$$

We have $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}  (0)=\lim_\limits{t\to0}\frac{f(tv)}{t}=\lim_\limits{t\to0}\frac{tf(v)}{t}=f(v).$

> At first I'd calculate the gradient

This is useless, since the function can be non-differentiable. For example for $f(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$ we have $\displaystyle f(tx, ty)=tf(x,y),\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  (0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0)=1$ but the formula $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}  =\nabla f\cdot v$ isn't true - the cause in nondifferentiability of $f$ at origin.

Comment: Typo in the first equation: $\partial f \over \partial v$

Comment: Nick, Thanks you. fixed.

Comment: O, nice - now in simple cases I can limit myself to comments